# Passenger (Rails)- way to restart via link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Has anyone found a decent way to restart Passenger via a link?  I need it for an admin so that they can just click a link (with a unique hash for protection) whenever our VPS provider has issues, if necessary.

I've tried having a secure link to a controller that just "touches" the tmp/restart.txt as well as writing to it, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize that this would need to be properly protected behind authentication and permission management right? Try using the `FileUtils` module from Ruby core.

You can use it by calling `FileUtils.touch(filename)` and its documentation is located [here](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/FileUtils.html#M001802).

Comment: Yes, it's behind authentication, permission mgmt, and a link with a randomized hash.  I was using `touch /pathtofilehere' instead; I'll try that.